# How Do I Push Oracle Data to an HTTP Server in JSON Format?

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, oracle

I'm setting up an online store whose inventory will be fed from a physical store's POS inventory data. The POS is backed by an Oracle database, ODBC-compliant. I need to create a script that executes the following process every 15 minutes:

1. Extract an on-hand inventory table from the oracle database.
2. Convert the table data into JSON.
3. Push the JSON data to an HTTP endpoint.

The developer on our team knows Visual Basic and has experience pulling data from the database. I'd just like some guidance on the best way to convert SQL data to JSON. I've come across the following tutorials but would like to know if there's a standard practice or existing library for this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/181230/Convert-DataSet-or-XML-to-JSON-using-VB-NET
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815371/Data-Parsing-SQL-to-JSON

Finally, what about HTTP POST with VB? Is there a standard library?

I have no experience with VB so I appreciate all your help!!!

Comment: You really don't need VB to do this. Have a look at UTL_HTTP package and you can get the data in JSON format with a single query. Can all be done in PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks maraca! What if there's some transformation I need to do? For example in the table there'd be "DESC1" and "COLOR" columns that in the json object would be an "SKU" key with value in the format of DESC1+COLOR.

Comment: Depending how your JSON should look like it can be a little difficult to write the query, in your case it would be something like: `select '{' || listagg('"' || sku || '":"' || desc1 || color || '"', ',') within group (order by sku) || '}' from articles`

Comment: also \ and " have to be escaped (replace with \\ and \", the former first) if they can appear in your columns, probably better to use a library for that too, but I have no experience with JSON libs.